# Error Running udev trigger for USB Insertion

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev

So I'm struggling to get a `udev` rule to work when I plug in my USB. I've read a lot of posts about how to do this with `udev`, but I'm coming across an error that I can't find much help on. When I plug in my USB, the rule does nothing.

This is the udev rule I got by following this [guide](http://www.techytalk.info/udev-rule-to-run-script-after-plugging-in-usb-device-on-ubuntu-linux-operating-system/):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0781", ATTR{idProduct}=="5591", RUN+=""/home/ubuntu/test.sh"
```

This is the bottom of the output from `/var/log/syslog` after inserting my USB:

```
Jun 18 21:51:30 ubuntu multipath: sdd: can't store path info
Jun 18 21:51:30 ubuntu multipathd[1146]: uevent trigger error
```

From what I'm seeing, it looks like the `udev` rule is right and gets triggered with the insertion of the USB, but it has an error actually running. Can someone please help me to understand what the error is here? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3.